# dot product of direction cosine vector

Tags: vectors

I have been reading a scientific paper and they defined Di as the direction cosine vector, [ cos(latitude of point i)cos(longitude of point i) , cos(latitude of point i)sin(longitude of point i), sin(latitude of point i)]'. The same was done for another coordinate j. Next the dot product of those two vectors (Di and Dj) was taken but I'm not sure what this actually represents. I would appreciate any help on what the result of the dot product is.

[This is the link of the paper](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1007%2Fs11038-012-9395-x/MediaObjects/11038_2012_9395_MOESM1_ESM.pdf), the part I am referring to is 2.2.1 Spatial weights matrix: W page 21, equation 16 contains di and dj from my question. I am currently trying to use this method but I am unable to obtain 's'. I have used equation 17 to obtain theta (b) but i have used theta as the [Angular distance equation from this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_distance) but I'm not sure if i should be using the di dot dj rather than the angular distance equation.

Sorry if this is too lengthy and unclear

Comment: It represents cosine of the angle between the two unit vectors. Can you provide more context? Myabe you could mention the paper and the page so we could look at. This might be e.g. when integrating over a surface in 3d, then $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$ is a normal unit vector to the surface multiplied by scalar $\mathrm{d}S$.

Comment: I just updated the question with all the links, sorry if my question wasnt clear

Comment: They somehow define "angular separation" or whatever in (16) and $\mathbf{d}_i\cdot\mathbf{d}_j$ is cosine of angle between vectors, as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction cosine vectors are normalized to unity, $|\vec D_i|=|\vec D_j|=1$. Then using the formula for dot product: $$\vec D_i\cdot\vec D_j=|\vec D_i||\vec D_j|\cos\alpha_{ij}=\cos\alpha_{ij}$$
Here $\alpha_{ij}$ is the angle between the two vectors.